# Get a variable from an array in perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am running a following command and getting the 4 lines as output.

```
userid@server:/home/userid# ps -ef|grep process
```

This is the output for the command.

```
userid  10117  9931  0 06:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep process
userid  15329     1  0 Jul11 ?        00:03:40 process APP1
userid  15334 15329  1 Jul11 ?        2-00:40:53 process1 APP1
userid  15390 15334  0 Jul11 ?        05:19:31 process2 APP1
```

I want to save the value APP1 to a variable using perl. So I want an output like `$APP = APP1`.

Comment: Use `split()` to split the line, then get the last element of the array.

Comment: I tried chomp and regex

Comment: @user2689092: Please show us the code that you tried, not a paraphrase.  Edit the question to show the code.

Comment: Your question is particularly poor: You provide no context for what you're doing, and demonstrate no attempt to solve it yourself. I have updated my answer - please see if this achieves what you want.

Comment: HINT: Instead of `ps -ef | grep process`, use `pgrep -f process`. This way, you'll see all the commands that use `process` without retrieving your `grep` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a single line command to get the required result.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $app1
$app1 = ( split /\s+/, `pgrep -f process1` )[-1];
print ($app1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (your output is in this case in the file `in.txt`):

```
perl -ne ' /(APP\d+)/g; print "$1\n";' in.txt
```

Prints:

```
APP1
APP1
APP1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using an array for the captured APPS1s would be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @apps;

while (<DATA>) {
    push @apps, $1 if /process\d*\s+(.+)/;
}

print "$_\n" for @apps;

__DATA__
userid  10117  9931  0 06:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep process
userid  15329     1  0 Jul11 ?        00:03:40 process APP1
userid  15334 15329  1 Jul11 ?        2-00:40:53 process1 APP1
userid  15390 15334  0 Jul11 ?        05:19:31 process2 APP1
```

Output:

```
APP1
APP1
APP1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `APP1` the last entry on the command line? Or, is it the second word after the `process*` command?

If it's the last *word* on the line, you could use this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $command_output, "|-", "pgrep -fl process";
while ( my $command = < $command_output > ) {
    $command =~ /(\w+)$/;
    my $app = $1;  #The last word on the line...
```

Otherwise, things get a bit more tricky. I am using `pgrep` instead of `ps -ef | grep`. The `ps` command returns a header, plus lots of fields. You need to split them, and parse them all. Plus, it even shows you the `grep` command you used to get the processes you're interested in.

The `pgrep` command with the `-f` and `-l` parameters returns no header and returns just the process ID followed by the full command. This makes it much easier to parse with a regular expression. (If you don't know about regular expressions, you need to [learn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) about them.)

```
open my $command_output, "|-", "pgrep -fl process";
while ( my $command = < $command_output > ) {
    if ( not $process =~ /^\d+\s+process\w+\s+(\w+)/ ) {
        next;
    }
    my $app = $1;  #The second word in the returned command...
```

There's no need to split or mess. There's no header to skip The regular expression matches the numeric process ID, the `process` command, and then selects the second word. I even check to make sure the output of the `pgrep` matches what I expect. Otherwise, I'll get the next line.